# Overflow: hidden property not working for after and before pseudo classes

Tags: css, sass, overflow

Basically I am trying to create a hexagonal shape, which would have a circle inside it and the extra parts of the circle should be hidden.
Demo: https://codepen.io/AskSaikatSinha/pen/jwXNPJ?editors=1100

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="radius-rect"></div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div id="hexagon" >
      <div class="semi-cir" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #0088CD;
    position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #0088CD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;

}
#hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;

}
#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.semi-cir{
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  background-color:#00A9F1;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-border-radius:75px;
  -moz-border-radius:75px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overflow: hidden does not have any effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give background color as same as it is given to 'semi-cir'.
same trick is applied on link provided by you : https://codepen.io/AskSaikatSinha/pen/jwXNPJ?editors=1100

```css
#hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #0088CD;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
  border-top: 1px solid #0088CD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;

}
#hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;

}
#hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #0088CD;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.semi-cir{
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  background-color:#00A9F1;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  -webkit-border-radius:75px;
  -moz-border-radius:75px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.radius-rect{
  height:200px;
  background:#00a9f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radius-rect"></div>
  <div class="hex">
    <div id="hexagon" >
      <div class="semi-cir" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

See the [definition of the `overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property by MDN:

> The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, show scrollbars, or display overflowing content when it is too large for its block-level container.
>
> (...)
>
> - **hidden**: Content is clipped if necessary to fit the content box. No scrollbars are provided.

The *content* of the element is clipped. Properties like `background`, `border` are *part* of the elements so are not clipped. You would have to apply `overflow: hidden` on the parent (`#hexagon`) to hide what is exceeding of the childreen (`.semi-cir`).

However, I do not know what you are thing to render precisely. If you simply want a "semi-circle" like the class name suggest, you can wrap your full circle in a parent with `overflow` just big enough to hide one of its half.

If you make like the circle is *inside* the hexagon with a non-linear separation, you can stack several of the "circles parts" described above.

But all of this is definitively over-engineered, and `overflow` is not the right property for that. You can take a look at the `clip` and `clip-path` properties that were made for this usecase.

> The clip CSS property defines what portion of an element is visible. The clip property applies only to absolutely positioned elements, that is elements with position:absolute or position:fixed.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip
>
> The clip-path CSS property prevents a portion of an element from getting displayed by defining a clipping region to be displayed i.e, only a specific region of the element is displayed. The clipping region is a path specified as a URL referencing an inline or external SVG, or shape method such as circle(). The clip-path property replaces the now deprecated clip property.
>
> -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Here are some great article about it:

- https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

However, be careful of the browser support. `clip` is deprecated and `clip-path` is [not supported by IE and Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Comment: Hi ncoden, I want to create http://www.commutatus.com/ logo in pure CSS
but the problem is if i add overflow: hidden in #hexagon then the :after and :before pseudo classes also gets clipped.

Comment: This is the expected behavior: all the content of the parent is hidden, pseudo-_elements_ included. For the logo you try to reproduce, you need to build the circle in several parts, or to use `clip-path`.